# error: format ‘%lu’ expects a matching ‘long unsigned int’ argument [-Werror=format=]

Tags: c, c99

How can i fix that `error`?. Searched a lot throw the web, but didn't found any similar problem.

compiled with gcc -Wall -Werror -std=c99
**Error Code:**

```
NameOfProgram: In function ‘main’:
NameOfProgram:17:23: error: format ‘%lu’ expects a matching ‘long unsigned int’ argument [-Werror=format=]
             printf("%lu , number");
                     ~~^
NameOfProgram:21:23: error: format ‘%lu’ expects a matching ‘long unsigned int’ argument [-Werror=format=]
             printf("%lu , number");
```

**Program in c99:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main(void) {

unsigned long number;
printf("Geben Sie irgendeine natürliche Zahl ein, die größer als 0 ist: ");
scanf(" %lu", &number);
printf("\n");

while(number > 0) {

    if(number % 2 == 0) {
        number = number / 2;
        printf("%lu , number");
    }
    else {
        number = (3 * number) + 1;
        printf("%lu , number");
    }
}


return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the syntax highlighing of the string in the `printf` calls. Where is the argument? Should it be *inside* the strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quotes are in the wrong place. Try this instead

```
printf("%lu", number);
```

But as a side note, it may be worth considering the more portable PRI notation. For example, if you have an explicit 32-bit unsigned integer, the print format string is different depending on compiler:

```
uint32_t number;
printf("My value is: %"PRIu32, number);
```